# How to create the texture in three.js and then render by shader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

**Now i have the array: `Uint8ClampedArray(size:512*512*4)`, i want to convert this array to the texture in three.js ,and then use the `Three.ShaderMaterial` to render the object.**

```
new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    vertexShader: document.querySelector( '#blendModel-vert').textContent.trim(),
    fragmentShader: document.querySelector( '#blendModel-frag' ).textContent.trim(),
    uniforms: {
        buffer:  { value: texture },
    }
});
```

the shader as follows:

```
<script id="blendModel-vert" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec4 gPosition;
    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gPosition=gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
</script>
<script id="blendModel-frag" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform sampler2D buffer;
    varying vec4 gPosition;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor.rgb = texture2D(buffer, vUv).rgb;
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at [`THREE.DataTextureLoader()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/DataTextureLoader).

Comment: the  Uint8ClampedArray(size:512*512*4) is the output of the function tf.toPixels()

Comment: You can draw a HTML canvas and then workaround like with texture.

Comment: There is also [`THREE.DataTexture()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/DataTexture).

Comment: but failed to render

Comment: have you done like so `var texture = new THREE.DataTexture( Your_data_array, 512, 512, THREE.RGBFormat );` if it doesn't work try `var texture = new THREE.DataTexture( new Uint8Array(Your_data_array), 512, 512, THREE.RGBFormat )`

Comment: I  have been tried to use ：var texture = new THREE.DataTexture( array, 512, 512, THREE.RGBAFormat );  And then the texture is a input of the shader,but it failed,it always render black./

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use [`Three.DataTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/DataTexture).
The data buffer which is provided to `Three.DataTexture`, has to be of type **`Uint8Array`** rather than `Uint8ClampedArray`. This is mentioned in the documentation.
The buffer has to consist of byte values in range [0, 255]:

e.g.

```js
let t_cx = 512;
let t_cy = 512;
let t_data = new Uint8Array(4 * t_cx * t_cy);

for ( let i = 0; i < t_cx; i ++ ) {
    for ( let j = 0; j < t_cy; j ++ ) {

        let id = j*t_cx*4 + i*4;

        let r = i / (t_cx-1);
        let g = j / (t_cx-1);
        let b = (1-r)*(1-g);

        t_data[id + 0] = r * 255;
        t_data[id + 1] = g * 255;
        t_data[id + 2] = b * 255;
        t_data[id + 3] = 255;
    }
}
```

Further more, the property [`.needsUpdate`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.needsUpdate) has to be set `true`, on the newly created texture object.

```js
var texture = new THREE.DataTexture( t_data, t_cx, t_cy, THREE.RGBAFormat );
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

It is also possible to create a temporary 2D canvas and image object. This can be load by `THREE.TextureLoader` as usual:

```js
let canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = t_cx;
canvas.height = t_cy;
let idata = ctx.createImageData( t_cx, t_cy );
idata.data.set( t_data );
ctx.putImageData( idata, 0, 0 );
let dataUri = canvas.toDataURL();

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( dataUri );

canvas.remove();
```

See the example:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var loader, camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -2);
    //camera.lookAt( -1, 0, 0 );

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();

  }

  function createModel() {

    let t_cx = 512;
    let t_cy = 512;
    let t_data = new Uint8Array(4 * t_cx * t_cy);

    for ( let i = 0; i < t_cx; i ++ ) {
        for ( let j = 0; j < t_cy; j ++ ) {
            
            let id = j*t_cx*4 + i*4;

            let r = i / (t_cx-1);
            let g = j / (t_cx-1);
            let b = (1-r)*(1-g);

            t_data[id + 0] = r * 255;
            t_data[id + 1] = g * 255;
            t_data[id + 2] = b * 255;
            t_data[id + 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    var testMode = 1
    var texture;

    if ( testMode == 1 ) {
        let canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = t_cx;
        canvas.height = t_cy;
        let idata = ctx.createImageData( t_cx, t_cy );
        idata.data.set( t_data );
        ctx.putImageData( idata, 0, 0 );
        let dataUri = canvas.toDataURL();
        
        texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( dataUri );

        canvas.remove();
    } else {
        texture = new THREE.DataTexture( t_data, t_cx, t_cy, THREE.RGBAFormat );
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    }
    

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
          uniforms : {
              buffer: {type: 't', value: texture}
          }
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
</script>
<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D buffer;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(buffer, vUv);
}
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```